# How to organize multiple projects each with different qa and live environment on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We have four different projects each having its own separate dev, qa and live environment.

Currently, we are using GCP to host all of them. In GCP we have 4 different "GCP projects". In our current setup:

1. A user can be part of more than one projects.
2. We have consolidated billing for all 4 projects.

Now, we are migrating to AWS.

In AWS , we can create organizations and organizational units. We can have an organization with 4 organizational units for each project or 4 different organizations, but we want to manage all 4 projects under the same account. Therefore this doesn't work for us.

Another approach I found is to use tagging.

We can tag each resource as project1-dev, project3-live etc.

IAM groups can be created for each tag like project1-dev, project2-live etc. Than we can assign IAM users to multiple groups.

Does this sound a good approach , or there is a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

1. > The limitation is that a member account can only be a part of a single organization or organizational unit at any given time
   > That's correct, but you can give the permission to read/create/modify resources in other accounts using
   > resource-policies.

   With resource-based policies, you can specify who has access to the resource and what actions they can perform on it. To learn
   whether principals in accounts outside of your zone of trust
   (trusted organization or account) have access to assume your roles

   More information → [access_policies_identity-vs-resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html)
2. Other solution is to create 4 organizations and create single
   account in each organization to the developer/QA/user and that
   person use named profiles on its computer that can be switched easy
   as `C:\> setx AWS_PROFILE development` or `C:\> setx AWS_PROFILE QA`
   [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html)